# Why do i keep getting Access allowed: <property object at 0x0000024D87D9CD68> in python3

Tags: python-3.x, class

It keeps printing " `Access allowed:<property object at 0x0000024D87D9CD68>in python`" instead of printing `"Enter the password:`". I don't know what the problem is. Please i need help knowing what part i missed to put me back on track.

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__ (self, firstname, lastname, money):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.money = money
        self.fullname = self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
        self._allowed_access = False
@property
def username(self):
    return '--> Fullname: {} || Money: {}'.format(self.fullname, self.money)

@property
def allowed_access(self):
    return self._allowed_access

@allowed_access.setter
def allowed_access(self, value):
    if value:
        password = input("Enter the password: ")
    if password == "Empress":
        self._allowed_access = value
    else:
        raise ValueError("Warning, Intruder Alert")

user_1 = BankAccount("Empress", "Obazee", 0)

print(user_1.username)

print("Access allowed: " + str(BankAccount.allowed_access))
BankAccount.allowed_access = True
print("Access allowed: " + str(BankAccount.allowed_access))

user_1.money = 10000
print(user_1.username)
```

Comment: `BankAccount` is the _class_. You probably meant `user_1.allowed_access`.

Comment: but it's not asking me for input to enter the password.

Comment: Because only the setter asks for the password. The getter doesn't.

Comment: so, why won't it? Am not getting it.

Comment: Resolved i get it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BankAccount:
def __init__ (self, firstname, lastname, money):
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname
    self.money = money
    self.fullname = self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
    self._allowed_access = False

@property
def username(self):
    return '--> Fullname: {} || Money: {}'.format(self.fullname, self.money)

@property
def allowed_access(self):
    return self._allowed_access

@allowed_access.setter
def allowed_access(self, value):
    if value:
        password = input("Enter the password: ")
    if password == "Empress":
        self._allowed_access = value
    else:
        raise ValueError("Warning, Intruder Alert")

user_1 = BankAccount("Empress", "Obazee", 0)

print(user_1.username)
print("Access allowed: " + str(user_1.allowed_access))
user_1.allowed_access = True
print("Access allowed: " + str(user_1.allowed_access))

user_1.money = 10000
print(user_1.username)
```